# JavaScript List Comparison and CRUD

Tags: javascript, crud

### Background

I'm trying to create a ordering system. The first array consist of 6 items (5 indexes) and the second array is empty. When the user clicks on an html item, it adds the item name from array1 to array2. I'm trying to make it dynamic, so if the user selects an item and if it's there in array2, this index will get removed, and if no, then will get added.

### Problem

Even after debugging and making sure it's easier to understand, I can't find why the list is erroring out. Weird random where the js is not working at all and even working, then giving errors like adding "," charecter etc..

### Arrays

These are the 2 arrays that are accessible for all functions:

```
const all_items = ['some item 1', 'some item 2', 'some item 3', 'some item 4', 'some item 5', 'some item 6'];
const order_items = [];
```

### Function: when item is clicked

When an item is clicked, this function is called.

```
function item_click(item) {
    if (item == 0) {
        if (isItemInOrder(all_items[0])) {
            var itemid = findItemIndex(all_items[0]);
            delete order_items[itemid];
            order_items = order_items.filter(element => {
                return element !== null;
            });
            document.getElementById("item0").classList.remove('bg:gray-100');
        } else {
            order_items.push(all_items[0]);
            document.getElementById("item0").className += " bg:gray-100";
        }
    } else if (item == 1) {
        if (isItemInOrder(all_items[1])) {
            var itemid = findItemIndex(all_items[1]);
            delete order_items[itemid];
            order_items = order_items.filter(element => {
                return element !== null;
            });
            document.getElementById("item1").classList.remove('bg:gray-100');
        } else {
            order_items.push(all_items[1]);
            document.getElementById("item1").className += " bg:gray-100";
        }
    } else if (item == 2) {
        if (isItemInOrder(all_items[2])) {
            var itemid = findItemIndex(all_items[2]);
            delete order_items[itemid];
            order_items = order_items.filter(element => {
                return element !== null;
            });
            document.getElementById("item2").classList.remove('bg:gray-100');
        } else {
            order_items.push(all_items[2]);
            document.getElementById("item2").className += " bg:gray-100";
        }
    } else if (item == 3) {
        if (isItemInOrder(all_items[3])) {
            var itemid = findItemIndex(all_items[3]);
            delete order_items[itemid];
            order_items = order_items.filter(element => {
                return element !== null;
            });
            document.getElementById("item3").classList.remove('bg:gray-100');
        } else {
            order_items.push(all_items[3]);
            document.getElementById("item3").className += " bg:gray-100";
        }
    } else if (item == 4) {
        if (isItemInOrder(all_items[4])) {
            var itemid = findItemIndex(all_items[4]);
            delete order_items[itemid];
            order_items = order_items.filter(element => {
                return element !== null;
            });
            document.getElementById("item4").classList.remove('bg:gray-100');
        } else {
            order_items.push(all_items[4]);
            document.getElementById("item4").className += " bg:gray-100";
        }
    } else if (item == 5) {
        if (isItemInOrder(all_items[5])) {
            var itemid = findItemIndex(all_items[5]);
            delete order_items[itemid];
            order_items = order_items.filter(element => {
                return element !== null;
            });
            document.getElementById("item5").classList.remove('bg:gray-100');
        } else {
            order_items.push(all_items[5]);
            document.getElementById("item5").className += " bg:gray-100";
        }
    }
}
```

### Function: find index of item in array

```
function findItemIndex(itemName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < order_items.length; i++) {
        if (order_items[i] === itemName) {
            return i;
            break;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### Function: find if an item is in order list

```
function isItemInOrder(itemName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < order_items.length; i++) {
        if (order_items[i] === itemName) {
            return true;
            break;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

I don't know how to perform this kind of CRUD operations. I have searched SO, youtube etc., and their CRUD operations are all related to ajax and files, but this one should've worked properly.

Comment: There are many built-in functions available to perform small tasks instead of `findItemIndex` you can use `findIndex`. For sorting, you can use `array.sort()`. instead of `delete` use `filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I quickly put together based on what you said using only pure javascript. Although I must say this seems like a bad way to implement an ordering system...

```js
const all_items = ['some item 1', 'some item 2', 'some item 3', 'some item 4', 'some item 5', 'some item 6'];
var order_items = [];

const itemList = document.getElementById("itemList");
const orderList = document.getElementById("orderList");

function handleClick(item){
  if(order_items.includes(item.innerHTML)){
    //remove item
    order_items = order_items.filter(e => e !== item.innerHTML);
  }else{
    //add item
    order_items.push(item.innerHTML);
  }
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('orderItem');
  while(items[0]) {
      items[0].parentNode.removeChild(items[0]);
  }
  order_items.forEach(item => {
    var i = document.createElement("li");
    i.setAttribute("class", "orderItem");
    i.innerHTML = item;
    orderList.appendChild(i);
  });
}

all_items.forEach(item => {
  var i = document.createElement("li");
  i.setAttribute("class", "item");
  i.innerHTML = item;
  i.setAttribute("onclick", "handleClick(this)");
  itemList.appendChild(i);
});
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item{
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.item:hover{
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>all items</h1>
<ul id="itemList">
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h1>orderd list</h1>
<ul id="orderList">
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. I will have to adjust it to match my html page tho. Because in my html page it does not populate the <ul> with <li>, since my css is different & the <li> has custom class names from tailwindcss. Maybe I'll try add html adjacent through js.

Comment: EDIT: I made it work and it's awesome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you with this coding problem.  This code performs what you asked in Background.  I did not include in this code any html manipulation because I feel it's important first to understand the algorithm, then add your ui code back in.

```
    const all_items = ['some item 1', 'some item 2', 'some item 3', 'some item 4', 'some item 5', 'some item 6'];
    const order_items: string[] = [];

    function order(index) {
        // see if the items from all_items[] is in order_items
        // indexOf will return the index if found otherwise -1
        const existing = order_items.indexOf(all_items[index]);
        if (existing >= 0) {
            // item found in order_items
            order_items.slice(existing, 1);         // remove item from order_items
        } else {
            // item not found in order_items
            order_items.push(all_items[index]);     // add item to order_items
        }
    }
```

If this helps you I will be happy to expand it to include your DOM manipulation logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This logic worked, however I marked csaseymour answer because it worked out of the box for me. This order logic is neater tho. Anyone facing similar issue, should try this out as well.